Best practice and performance for processing binary-file to objects and back
The following code samples are working, so I don't have an actual issue, but hope to get some feedback and suggestions for optimisation and best practices. This question was already asked in CodeReview, but was closed and deleted there, because of "missing review context".
I often work with binary files, which I process using C#.
The data formats are very specific depending on the application, but the white paper specifies exactly which bytes code which values.
An example of a file or data format would be ASPRS LAS (of course this format is a bit more complex than the question example below).
Let's assume a simple case that the binary file consists of many identical data packets.
So far, I would write a class that contains one data record from the binary file. In the assumed case, I would process the entire binary file into an array of objects of this class.
Assume a data packet contains the following data:
int
char[32]
float
float
int
double

My class would look like this:
public class Packet
{
    private int _id;
    private char[] _text;
    private float _value1;
    private float _value2;
    private int _value3;
    private double _value4;

    // properties...
    // etc.

    // constructor 1 to read packet value by value
    public Record(BinaryFile bf)
    {
        _id = bf.ReadInt();
        _text = bf.ReadString(32).ToCharArray();
        _value1 = bf.ReadFloat();
        _value2 = bf.ReadFloat();
        _value3 = bf.ReadInt();
        _value4 = bf.ReadDouble();
    }
    // constructor 2 to create object from previously read byte-array
    public Record(ref byte[] data, ref int startindex)
    {
        _id = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, startindex);
        startindex += 4;
        _text = new char[32];
        for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            _text[i] = (char)data[startindex+i];
        }
        startindex += 32;
        // etc...
    }


    // getter/setter methods...


    // method 1 to write packet value by value
    public void WriteToFile(BinaryFile bf)
    {
        bf.WriteInt(_id);
        for(int i = 0; i < _text.Length; i++)
        {
            bf.WriteChar(_text[i]);
        }
        bf.WriteFloat(_value1);
        // etc...
    }
    // method 2 to return bytes of packet to write it as a whole into the file later
    public byte[] GetBytes()
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[56];
        Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(_id), 0, bytes, 0, 4);
        Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(_text), 0, bytes, 4, 32);
        Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(_value1), 0, bytes, 36, 4);
        // etc.
        return bytes;
    }

    // etc.
}

Here is an excerpt from my BinaryFile class to show how it works:
public class BinaryFile
{
    // ...

    public int ReadInt(ByteOrder byteOrder)
    {
        byte[] ret = ReadBytes(4, byteOrder);
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(ret, 0);
    }

    public byte[] ReadBytes(int numberOfBytes, ByteOrder byteOrder)
    {
        if (numberOfBytes < 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("...");
        }

        // prepare Array
        byte[] ret = new byte[numberOfBytes];
        // read bytes
        this._fileStream.Read(ret, 0, numberOfBytes);
        // check byte-order
        if (byteOrder == ByteOrder.BigEndian)
        {
            Array.Reverse(ret);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    // etc...
}

As user555045 asked in CodeReview: BinaryFile could also be exchanged by System.IO.BinaryReader for reading and System.IO.BinaryWriter for writing the file.
I would then iterate over the array and access the individual values of a Packet object either via getter and setter methods or via properties. Some data would have to be changed, some data not. After processing, if changes have been made, I would write the file back to the hard drive.
In my opinion, the procedure in the first constructor/write-method is easy to understand, but naturally somewhat slower, as all values are read/written individually.
The second constructor receives the reference to the entire file in form of a byte-array and processes the values itself, which is faster, but not as easy to understand and also a bit more error-prone (startindex += ...). Also method two, which returns the byte array, feels kind of awkward.
Does this approach (to have a hard-coded field for every value of the packet) make sense in principle, or not?
Would it be better if the class only contained a byte array and the corresponding values were only converted when accessed via a method or a property? Are there any advantages or disadvantages with this variant in terms of performance and memory usage (or other)? Reading and writing the file would probably be a lot faster, but processing the individual values probably not?
However, I then come to the point that I could read in the entire file as a byte array and calculate the byte offset of the individual data records when accessing and then convert the corresponding values if necessary. That way I wouldn't have to create 1000s (or even millions) of objects of this class, but I would have to calculate much more. This would be even more complex, if the data-packet size would differ from packet to packet. Another potential problem would be, if I would have to change the size of a data packet. Then I would have to recreate the whole array for each altered packet. This would be even more unfavourable if the file is at least half the size of the available RAM...
I often have to iterate over each data record of the file in a loop, so it would probably make no sense (in terms of IO) not to read the file at all, but to access it directly on the hard disc?
As this is a simple example and real-world-files are often more complex, a serialization-approach wouldn't work (also commented by user555045).

Originally you say "The data formats are very specific depending on the application", then you say "This would be even more complex, if the data-packet size would differ from packet to packet." Which is it  - is the data very specifically defined or does it "differ from packet to packet"?

Also there is little point in commenting on a "simple example" when your "real world files" are more complex and wouldn't work the same way.

depending on the file format (eg. LAS PointDataRecords [same length] or eg. echosounder-data [variable length]) the length of the individual packets may vary. As my question is intended to determine whether the procedure described is fundamentally appropriate, I have chosen a simple example.

BinaryReader/BinaryWriter are "opinionated" - they are not general purpose IO pieces. BitConverter should be considered deprecated by BinaryPrimitives. If the frames are fixed size, this whole thing might be (after an endianess check) a single "pun" of a span - heck, the entire thing could be an Unsafe-Cast of a large span, perhaps via MMF. Lots of potential here, but more than can reasonably be explained here. Even for variable size: span readers using ref-structs can be blindingly efficient.

@MarcGravell thank you for pointing me to BinaryPrimitives, MMF and spans - lot of research to be done by me! I think this would be an elegant solution for simpler files. I will probably ask a separate question for this approach for more complex files.
But the main question remains: Is it better to create an object (of a class or struct) with fields for each value, or with a simple byte-array together with properties/methods doing conversion when accessing the values? As I don't need to access every value of the packet when processing it, maybe variant two is more efficient?

@SaschaP there are a ton of ways of approaching this, and "better" is subjective; for example, you could simply scan over the data reading the length data (the first int presumably?), and just noting the byte offsets of each object; or you could create a struct for each; if the 32 is a max length in bytes, it might be reasonable to use a fixed buffer for that in a struct (probably not class) - you probably wouldn't want to create a string for each text unless you know you want it. Honestly, this is a very nuanced topic, and specific design goals: matter
